# How To Create New Column Based Off of Secondary ID Column Utilizing Data Connected to Primary ID Column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, data-cleaning

This is a little complicated to explain. I had a set of [speed dating data off of Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/annavictoria/speed-dating-experiment) and there's a column of `Subject_IDs` and `Partner_IDs` (how I renamed the data). There are columns such as race and gender connected to the `Subject_IDs` but every subject is also a partner in the dataset. And I want to create columns of Partner_Race and Partner_Gender based on the columns I renamed as `Subject_Gender` and `Subject_Race`.

edit: to clarify, the `Partner_IDs` are the same people in the `Subject_IDs` and use the same ID numbers. They're just put into different columns.

I'm really lost at the logical steps I would even need to take to do this. Of course, my data is longer than just six observations or I'd have just manually do it. I would have a preference for dplyr or plyr methods but if that's not possible, that's okay

My data looks like:

```
Subject_ID     Partner_ID     Subject_Race      Subject_Gender
   1               6            Caucasian          Female
   2               5             Asian              Male
   3               4         African_American      Female
   4               3             Other             Female
   5               2             Latin              Male
   6               1               NA               Male
```

And here's what I want to create

```
Subject_ID     Partner_ID     Subject_Race      Subject_Gender      **Partner_Race     Partner Gender**
   1               6            Caucasian          Female                NA               Male
   2               5             Asian              Male               Latino             Male
   3               4         African_American      Female               Other            Female
   4               3             Other             Female          African_American      Female
   5               2             Latino             Male                Asian             Male
   6               1               NA               Male              Caucasian          Female
```

I'm still at the very basics of data cleaning and argumentation. And this is above my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the data by itself and the columns `Partner_ID` and `Subject_ID`.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Subject_ID     Partner_ID     Subject_Race      Subject_Gender
   1               6            Caucasian          Female
                 2               5             Asian              Male
                 3               4         African_American      Female
                 4               3             Other             Female
                 5               2             Latin              Male
                 6               1               NA               Male", header = T)


library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  dplyr::left_join(df, by = c("Subject_ID" = "Partner_ID"),
            suffix = c("", "_Partner")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Subject_ID_Partner, 
         Partner_Gender = Subject_Gender_Partner,
         Partner_Race = Subject_Race_Partner)
```

**Output:**

```
  Subject_ID Partner_ID     Subject_Race Subject_Gender     Partner_Race Partner_Gender
1          1          6        Caucasian         Female             <NA>           Male
2          2          5            Asian           Male            Latin           Male
3          3          4 African_American         Female            Other         Female
4          4          3            Other         Female African_American         Female
5          5          2            Latin           Male            Asian           Male
6          6          1             <NA>           Male        Caucasian         Female
>
```